# Can I keep my files intact while upgrading ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, 13.04, data-loss

I am planning to upgrade to ubuntu 13.04 from 12.10 when it is going to be launched on 25 April. My files storage  memory is 300GB and I do not want to buy another external HDD to create a backup and save hours creating another backup.

There is another question in ask ubuntu with the same doubt but the answer in that question had made me lose all my data while upgrading to 12.10 from 12.04 earlier in the year.

How can I do the distro upgrade while keeping my files intact with a guarantee.

Comment: If you care about your data back it up.  Things can go wrong -- hardware can fail.  You only need to backup the data that is unique to you not programs etc.

Comment: Also, Saket, what "answer" / "question" were you using when you "first" upgraded (to 12.10)?

Answer (score 8):

There is no guarantee all your files will be intact. There's no way to give such a guarantee effectively.

You can upgrade-in-place (command line: `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`, i think) once Raring is released, but there's still the risk of data loss, either because the upgrade fails and your system is bricked, or many other reasons, including random hardware failure.